# Two models in backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone-model

I have been trying to display two models in one view. Here is my code:

On router part- fetch models of about us and company and add them to AboutusView:

```
var self=this;
var aboutus=new Aboutus({id:1});
var company= new Company({id:1});
aboutus.fetch();
company.fetch();


var model = new Backbone.Model();
model.set({aboutus: aboutus, company: company});
var aboutusView=new AboutusView({model:aboutus,model2:company});
aboutusView.render();
self.changePage(aboutusView);


=======================

For Aboutus View Part:


var AboutusView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template(aboutusViewTemplate),

initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

},


render: function(){

console.log(this.model);
console.log(this.options.model2);


this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

  return this;
}
});

return AboutusView;




============================
In console log of this.model (aboutus) is:
===========================
 child {attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c0", changed: Object,     _silent: Object…}
 _changing: false
 _escapedAttributes: Object
 _pending: Object
 _previousAttributes: Object
 _silent: Object
  attributes: Object
     aboutusId: 1
     description: "testing" 
      id: 1
       imageExtension: ""
       title: "ABOUT US"
 __proto__: Object
 changed: Object
  cid: "c0"
  id: 1
 __proto__: ctor
```

So the question is I want to display aboutus attributes such as aboutusId, description in template. How can i do that?

Comment: where is the definition of aboutusViewTemplate

Comment: @eguneys aboutusViewTemplate is just html template to show data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending this.model.toJSON() to your template, send both datasets (models). Keep in mind that you can send any type of JSON object to a template. You could do something like:

```
var somedata = {
    aboutus: this.model.toJSON(),
    company: this.options.model2.toJSON() //or 'this.model2.toJSON()', not completely sure where this model is accessible in the view.
    }

this.$el.html(this.template(somedata));
```

Then in your template you can access each model by `<%= aboutus.description %>` or `<%=company.id %>` (for example).

Comment: Actually this.model is not model it is returning child (as show in above) Any idea on how to retrieve the attributes inside the child

Comment: Oh, I see. I added a new answer below. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
model.set({aboutus: aboutus, company: company});
var aboutusView=new AboutusView({model:aboutus,model2:company});
```

In these lines above, you create the var `model` but never add attach `model` to the `AboutusView`. Wouldn't you want to do:

```
var aboutusView=new AboutusView({model:model});
```

In doing so, you have now a model, called `model` that has attributes `aboutus` and `company`, which you can access in your template by passing `model.toJSON()` in your template.

If Aboutus and Company are also models (I assume they are), you can access their attributes in your view by:

```
this.model.get('aboutus').get('id')
```